# jQuery: How to hyperlink to filter out html tags in display?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, filter, undefined

For this Twitter clone I need to take 10 randomly generated tweets that have a username and message, and then when you click on their handle, only display that user's tweets.

My problem is that whenever I attempt to hyperlink to a function, I am met with "foo() is not a function" (unless my function is a simple alert('your anchor is working');)

I think this may be because I am not familiar with event listeners and still do not quite understand them but my deadline is coming up and I would love some pointers(:

Here's my jQuery code. It basically pushes each tweet into the   tag and then attempts to sort out only the  tweets in  that have the clicked' hyperlink's literal text in it (which I can get from ".innerHTML" even though it's maybe "bad practice"?).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var index = streams.home.length - 1;
  while (index >= 0) {
    var d = new Date();
    var time = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds();
    var user = $('tweet.user');
    var tweet = streams.home[index];
    var name = tweet.user;
    var $tweet = $('<li>');
    ("#tweets").className = user.toString();
    $tweet.html('<a href=javascript:void(0); onclick= \"filterUsers()\">' + tweet.user + "</a><br><span>" + tweet.message + "<br>" + "~Twiddled at " + time + '~<span>');
    $tweet.appendTo("#tweets");
    index -= 1;
  };

  $('.tweets').css('text-align', 'center');

  function filterUsers() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById('tweets');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("tweets");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
      a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
      txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
      if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Twiddler</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="data_generator.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="background: limegreen">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <div id="logo">
        <a href="index.html">
          <img src="twiddlerLogo.png">
        </a>
      </div>
      <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="searchUser()" search="Search for names">
    </div>
    <div class="wall-container">
      <section class="tweets-container">
        <div id="tweets"></div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

A search function I tried implementing that brings up the "foo() is not defined" error when I type in my search box

```
function searchFunction(user) {
  var allTweets = document.getElementsByClassName("tweets").getElementsByTagName("li");
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(allTweets).filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
```

Comment: Move the function declaration outside of `$(document).ready..` in order for it to be available in the `onclick` which requires access to global scope functions only

Comment: I see numerous other issues with your code also that will require tweaking/debugging

Comment: Ah, that makes sense thanks! I'll try my best to debug it then

Comment: Oh! Yeah, there's some pretty glaring bugs here (I don't even have a <ul> tag in my code!). It's because I tried so many methods that I lose track of things. Thanks again, putting the function outside of doc ready seems to have fixed the main problem I was facing!